# I'm having this Error when I'm debugging and building my Flutter Project on VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, visual-studio-code

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.1/lib/src/io_client.dart:30:72: Error: Expected ';' after this.

```
  var ioRequest = await _inner!.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
                                                                   ^
```

../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.1/lib/src/io_client.dart:30:73: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ')'.

Try inserting an identifier before ')'.

```
  var ioRequest = await _inner!.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
                                                                    ^
```

../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.1/lib/src/io_client.dart:30:73: Error: Expected ';' after this.

```
  var ioRequest = await _inner!.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
                                                                    ^
```

../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.1/lib/src/io_client.dart:30:73: Error: Unexpected token ')'.

```
  var ioRequest = await _inner!.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
                                                                    ^
```

../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.1/lib/src/io_client.dart:32:9: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '..'.
Try inserting an identifier before '..'.
..followRedirects = request.followRedirects
^^